# Where do I find the "get-pip.py" dowload link?

Tags: python, iphone, swift, pip

I as part of a tutorial am trying to download pip.py but the link is different now and I can't find a button which I can download pip.

This is the link I get: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#cmdoption-no-setuptools

Anyone know where I can find the download?

Comment: It should be located in the Scripts folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read the docs? ie:

> Do I need to install pip? pip is already installed if you are using
>   Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 downloaded from python.org or if
>   you are working in a Virtual Environment created by virtualenv or
>   pyvenv. Just make sure to upgrade pip.
>
> Installing with get-pip.py To install pip, securely download
>   get-pip.py. [1]:
>
> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

Comment: this link takes me to a long scrip... I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: @neburRB That's a python script, therefore you need to execute it with python, ie `python get-pip.py` or just `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py | python`. In any case, did you check pip wasn't installed already? Did you read the section of the docs I've pasted?

Comment: No, it's not installed... So should I just install python3 it in order to get pip.py?

Comment: That's correct, you don't mention the operating system you're using but by installing python properly you'll get pip just for free without having to run these additional scripts. Just make sure you install python properly and then you'll just have pip up-and-running out of the box.