# messed up pip for python 2.7.16 and upgraded it to pip v 21.1.2

Tags: python, macos, pip

**specs:**

*macOs BigSur*

*Iterm2 with ohmyzsh*

*preinstalled with python2.7.16 & python 3.9.5*

**Problem :**

i upgraded pip without pyenv , so now both pip and pip3 refer to python 3.9.5

i made an alias for python 3.9.5 to be default in .zshrc file

i also used pip to install flask

**Questions :**

Do i donwgrade pip for python2.7.16?

Or re install python2.7.16 with its pip?

i know i must have used pyenv but; is it possible now ? after 2 versions already installed?

```
* system (set by /Users/johnDoe/.pyenv/version)
➜  ~ python2 --version
Python 2.7.16
➜  ~ python3 --version
Python 3.9.5
➜  ~ pip --version
pip 21.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
➜  ~ pip3 --version
pip 21.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
➜  ~ pip freeze
click==8.0.1
Flask==2.0.1
itsdangerous==2.0.1
Jinja2==3.0.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
Werkzeug==2.0.1

➜  ~ where python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python
➜  ~ where python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
➜  ~ where pip
pip: aliased to /usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
➜  ~ where pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
➜  ~ which pip
pip: aliased to /usr/local/bin/pip3
➜  ~ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
➜  ~ which python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3
➜  ~ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
➜  ~ which python2
/usr/bin/python2
➜  ~ where flask
/usr/local/bin/flask
/usr/local/bin/flask
➜  ~ which flask
/usr/local/bin/flask
```

Comment: I would recommend you check what version of pip your Python 2.7 instance has. You can check with `python2 -m pip list`. I would think pip wouldn't let you install a version of itself without first checking all dependencies.

Comment: System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip

Comment: Found this on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694205/where-do-i-find-the-get-pip-py-dowload-link

Comment: Thanks for adding the list of your `which` commands. That really helped getting you your answer.

Comment: what about having double "same location" for the where command for pip and python?

Comment: For that, I'd inspect your `PATH` environment variable. It might have `/usr/local/bin` multiple times. I am still on Mojave (32-bit apps) but I would think fundamentally things work the same way.

Comment: Thanks Ben Y i appreciate your time and effort :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should downgrade the `pip` package of your Python 2 installation as [Pip 21.0 dropped supported for Python 2](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v21-0).

For some reason, the `pip` command on your system refers to the Python 3 installation. One would think there'd be two commands, `pip2` and `pip3`, just as for the Python interpreter.

Therefore, run the following command to downgrade Pip for Python 2 to the last supported version:

```
python2 -m pip install "pip<21.0"
```

Here `pip` is called "as a module" *via* `python2`. This makes sure it uses the Pip package manager of the Python 2 installation, and not the (separate) one for Python 3.

Comment: thats what i got 
```➜  ~ python2 -m pip install "pip<21.0"
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have pip for your Python 2.7 environment. You might need to run the bootstrap script using python 2.7 to get it installed there. (I think it was called `get_pip.py`)

Comment: if it wasn't there i guess i don't need to have it . right? since i need it only for the system (macOs) i won't be using it , only using python 3, so its safe to leave it like that?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that Python 2 series is no longer supported, have you checked to see if `pip` for Python 2.7 is aliased to `pip2`? You appear to be able to still access the 2.7 interpreter with `python2`, so another way to run **pip** is `python2 -m pip <command>`.